# Facebook JS SDK : Alternatives to popup box of FB.Login

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook JS SDK to develop a Facebook Page Tab application. There is a button in landing page. When clicked, user will be asked to install the App if they haven't done so.

The codes are as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function installApp() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        }
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            window.location = 'share.php';
        } else {
            alert('Please install app first');
        }
    }, {scope:'friends_likes,email'});
}
</script>
```

By default [FB.Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) will result in a popup box asking for permission. Is there any alternative way to AVOID the popup box? I have seen other Facebook apps successfully achieve this, but I have no idea how they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you went through the [Authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)?

It pretty much cover all of the options that are available to you. i.e.:

1. [Client-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/)
2. [Server-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)
3. [Authentication within a Page Tab](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/)

You can probably use any of those approaches, but the 3rd probably will fit best.

Comment: I hate it how people accept answers and never post how this answer helped them exactly. :\

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Javascript Api with a Graph Api call for this,

```
function fbLogin() {
    var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
    oauth_url += '?client_id=APP_ID_HERE';
    oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/');
    oauth_url += '&scope=email'
    window.top.location = oauth_url;
}
```

then you can call it in a custom button with the onclick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return fbLogin();">Custom Login</a>
```

Comment: This method still works great in 2017!! Avoid the popup! Just make sure the redirect_uri is correct, you may have to add it to the app's domain list